# What is equivalent of "direct to template" in class based view in django

Tags: django

I used to do this when function based generic views were there

```
 (r'^foo/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'foo_index.html'}),
```

what is the equvalent of this in class based views so that i don't need to define anything in my `views.py`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView), and you use it like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^foo/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='foo_index.html')),
)
```

Comment: i am trying to import from `django.views.generic` and its working fine. why do i need from `django.views.generic.base` is it different

Comment: You can [see in the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/__init__.py) that `django.views.generic` just imports `TemplateView` from `django.views.generic.base`; they're exactly the same.